# How to find the maximum lag in a list of cross correlations in R (ccf)?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, max, cross-correlation

This is an example of my data:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4)
Affect <- c(0.8, 0.5, NA, 0.8, 0.2, 0.1, 0.7, 1.1, 0.9, 0.5, 0.3, NA, 0.9)
Paranoia <-  c(0.9, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1, NA, 0.3, 0.1, 0.9, 1.5, 0.4, 0.1, 0.6)
both <- data.frame(id, Affect, Paranoia)
```

Now I calculate a cross correlation for each ID seperately, which gives me a list:

```
library(tseries)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
out <- both %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(!(all(is.na(Affect))|all(is.na(Paranoia)))) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Affect, Paranoia), replace_na, 0) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(ccfout = list(ccf(Affect, Paranoia, ylim=c(-10, 10), lag.max=5)))
```

What I want to do now is to find the lag at which the correlation is at its maximum and the correlation value at that point for each ID - tried this, but didn't work, probably because I have the list for each ID:

```
Find_Max_CCF <- function(Affect,Paranoia)
{
  d<- both %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    filter(!(all(is.na(Affect))|all(is.na(Paranoia)))) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(Affect, Paranoia), replace_na, 0) %>% 
    dplyr::summarise(ccfout = list(ccf(Affect, Paranoia, ylim=c(-10, 10))))
  cor = d$acf[,,1]
  lag = d$lag[,,1]
  res = data.frame(cor,lag)
  res_max = res[which.max(res$cor),]
  return(res_max)
}

Find_Max_CCF(both)
```

The error message is:

```
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'acf'. 
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'lag'. 
3: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'acf'. 
4: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'lag'
```

Do you have any ideas?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `cor = d$acf[,,1]` here you are trying to subset a column that you have not created in the code above.

Comment: Thank you for that hint @LyzandeR. As I am quite new to R, do you have a suggestion how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the column `ccfout` you create contains lists of `acf` objects, whereas you want them to be dataframes to be able to slice the way you try to.
I wrote a function `ccf_as_df` that instead returns `list`s of `data.frame` objects, with columns `lag` and `ccf`, by extracting those from the `acf` object that `ccf()` returns.

```
ccf_as_df <- function(x, y) {
  # calculate ccf and return it as a list of a dataframe
  # with columns `lag` and `acf`
  ccf_obj <- ccf(x, y, ylim=c(-10, 10), lag.max=5, plot = F)
  ccf_df <- data.frame(lag = as.vector(ccf_obj$lag), ccf = as.vector(ccf_obj$acf))
  return(list(ccf_df))
}

out <- both %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(!(all(is.na(Affect))|all(is.na(Paranoia)))) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Affect, Paranoia), replace_na, 0) %>% 
  summarise(ccfout = ccf_as_df(Affect, Paranoia))
```

Now, the `ccfout` column contains lists of `dataframe`s, which you can unnest to get a dataframe with three columns: `id`, `lag` and `ccf`.
This can then be grouped by `id` to get the maximum `ccf` and the `lag` at which this occurs:

```
out %>% 
  unnest(ccfout) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(max_ccf = max(ccf),
            max_ccf_lag = lag[which.max(ccf)])
```

Comment: Hey @Bas, thank you, it works perfectly with the data I posted here. But when I use my real data frame, I get an error message: ```Column `max_ccf_lag` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 0```. Do you have any idea why this is?

Comment: It means that the `ccf` column has 0 observations for that value of `id`. That might be because all observations were `NA` and you removed them. You can do `out %>% unnest(ccfout) %>% count(id)` to see how many rows you have per `id`. Also having only 1 observation is problematic, I think, since then `ccf` might not be defined.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I get: `> out %>% unnest(ccfout) %>% count(id) # A tibble: 143 x 2 id n <dbl> <int> 1 12 11 2 14 11 3 15 11 4 16 11 5 17 11 6 18 11 7 19 11 8 20 11 9 22 11 10 23 11 # ... with 133 more rows ` - looks for me as if there were observations for each ids, or am I wrong?

Comment: Do `out %>% unnest(ccfout) %>% count(id) %>% filter(n < 2)` to check if there are `id`s with fewer than 2 observations.

Comment: Seems not to be the case: `# A tibble: 0 x 2
# ... with 2 variables: id <dbl>, n <int>`

Comment: Most likely there are `id`s for which `Affect` and `Paranoia` have a cross correlation that's `NaN`. You can remove these by doing a `filter(!is.na(ccf))` after `unnest(ccfout)`, or replace them with something such as `replace_na(list(ccf = -Inf))`. Then, in your final result check for the rows where `max_ccf` is `-Inf`.